# How can I keep gnu screen from becoming unresponsive after losing my SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, hung

I use a VPN tunnel to connect to my work network and then SSH to connect to my work PC running cygwin.  Once logged in I can attach to a screen session and everything works great.

Now, after a while, I walk away from my computer and sooner or later, the VPN tunnel times out.  The SSH connection on each end eventually times out and then I eventually come back to my computer to do some work.  Theoretically, this should be a simple matter of just restarting the VPN, reconnecting via SSH, and then running "screen -r -d".

However apparently when the sshd daemon times out on the cygwin PC, it leaves the screen session in some kind of hung state.  I can reproduce a similar hung state by clicking the close box on a cygwin bash shell window while it's running a screen session.

Is there any way to get the screen session to recover once this has happened, so that I don't lose anything?

Comment: The FAQ says: "software tools commonly used by programmers".  The tools I described seem relevant to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a great deal of experimentation, I was able to recover the screen session as follows:

1. Lookup the PID of the server screen process: ps | grep screen
2. Send the server a HUP signal: kill -1 <PID>
3. Run a screen client: screen -r -d

Answer (score 3):

`screen` is blocking on the (dead) SSH session's pty.  Recover by killing that `sshd`.

Assuming Linux, and that you're not currently inside screen:

```
$ pgrep -U $UID sshd | xargs -rn1 pstree -hp
sshd(16305)───bash(16306)───screen(16670)
sshd(16544)───bash(16545)───xargs(16705)───pstree(16707)
$ kill 16305
$ screen -r
```

Comment: I don't see the sshd process running any more -- there doesn't appear to be anything to kill except the screen process and the bash shells running within it.  As you would guess, killing them doesn't help matters :/

Comment: @Mikey: Try without the `-U $UID`.  I'd be surprised, but maybe you're not running a sshd with privilege separation…

Comment: Maybe cygwin is different in this regard than linux.  The sshd process is missing from both the "ps -efW" output and from the "Process Explorer" output.  When sshd is running, it is invoked by the cygwin SSH service as follows: "C:\cygwin\usr\sbin\sshd.exe -D -R".  The -D flag controls whether to to detach and the -R flag doesn't appear documented on the man page.